# Creating Cycle.js reusable modules

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, cyclejs

Let's imagine, in a OO world, I want to build a `Torrent` object which listens to the network and lets me interact with it. It would inherit an EventEmitter and would look something like this:

```
var torrent = new Torrent(opts)
torrent.on('ready', cb) // add torrent to the UI
torrent.on('metadata', cb) // update data in the UI
```

and I can also make it do things:

```
torrent.stop()
torrent.resume()
```

Then of course if I want to do delete the torrent from memory I can call `torrent.destroy()`.

The cool thing about this OO approach is that I can easily package this functionality in its own npm module, test the hell out of, and give users a nice clean reusable API.

My question is, how do I achieve this with Cycle.js apps?

If I create a driver it's unclear how I would go about creating many torrents and having their own independent listeners. Also consider I'd like to package functionality in a way that others get to easily reuse it in other Cycle.js apps.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are trying to solve a problem thinking about it as you would write ["imperative code"](http://staltz.com/its-easy-to-write-imperative.html).
I think creating Torrent instances with their own listeners is not something you should be using in cycle components.

I would go about it differently - creating Torrent module and figuring out what would be its sources and sinks. If this module should be reusable and published, you can create it as a function that would receive streams as arguments. Maybe something similar to [TodoMVC Task component](https://github.com/cyclejs/todomvc-cycle/blob/master/src/components/Task/index.js) (which is then used in its parent component).

Since this module can be created as a pure function, testing it should be at least just as easy.

This implementation of course depends on your requirements but communication with the module would then be done only with streams and since it would be declarative there would be no need for methods like stop() and destroyed() which you would call from elsewhere.

Comment: Yes I think I'm having problems thinking about it in a functional way rather than imperative. So you're saying I would have a TorrentDriver to which I can send sources and create torrent instances? It's confusing to understand where my actual "torrent object" will be. Because it needs to be in memory somewhere.

Comment: This function (and probably not driver) would not return instances - that would be a "functional way". It should return only streams which you can then use and react to it. So the source would be something on which torrents should be created (some DOM events or actions etc) and sink (returned stream) would be some kind of results you can use in your app (stream used in view for writing in DOM or some data stream). It depends really on what you wish to accomplish, but generally for creating instances and using them like you wanted is not something cycle component would do...

Answer (score 0):

> How do I test it?

In cycle.js you'd write a component with intent model and view functions.

You'd test intent(), for given input Streams, produces Streams of actions that you want. For models, you'd test that given http and action streams, you get the state you want, and for view, you test that given a state you get the VDom you want.

One tricky bit with cycle.js is that since it passes functions around, normal JavaScript objects that use the 'this' keyword are not worth the trouble due to 'this' context problems. If you are working with cycle.js and you think you might write a JS class for use with Isolate, Onionify, or Collections most likely, you are going in the wrong direction. See [MDN docs about 'this'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

> how I would go about creating many torrents

The Cycle.js people have several ways to deal with groups of things like this. 
This [ticket](https://github.com/cyclejs/cyclejs/issues/312) describes some things that might work for that:

- Wrap subapp in Web Component
- Stanga and similars.
- [Cycle Collections](https://github.com/cyclejs/collection)
- [Cycle Onionify](https://github.com/staltz/cycle-onionify)